# How to activate modal view before any views activated

Tags: javascript, durandal-2.0

I'm hooking the canActivate callback to load a login model/view.  My welcome view shows the login dialog in the activate callback, which works just fine.  I would like to block activation of all views with the login, rather than simply calling it after view activation.  It seems like my login model/view won't load unless at least one other view is loaded.  Once I load welcome, I can get the model to display fine when attempting to navigate to other views where it is hooked into canActivate.

Here's what it looks like in my welcome model:

```
self.activate = function () {
      if( session.token() == null){
          app.showDialog(new Login())
        }
    }
```

and what it looks like in my other models:

```
self.canActivate = function () {
      if( session.token() == null){
        return app.showDialog(new Login()).then(function(){
          return true;
        })      
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    }
```

The canActivate is returned a promise from the login dialog and only activates after the dialog closes itself on successful login.  Can I show the dialog before activating any view?

Comment: What if you move the canActivate code into the activate function ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to use login page-viewmodel and route-redirect to it on each viewmodel canActivate (on views that require authentication) when not logged in.
When this happens you save the current route to some global-app level variable.
Then once logged in you redirect back to the view you where visiting first.

Example CanActivate (Typescript):

> ```
> public canActivate(parms?: any): any {
>     return this.doRequireLogin ? Q.resolve(this.app.requireLogin(this.modelId)) : true;
> }
> ```

The app requireLogin example logic:

> ```
> public requireLogin(moduleId: string): boolean {
>     this.pageModuleId = moduleId;
>     if (this.isLogedIn())
>         return true;
>     else {
>         if (this.loginPageIdFrom == '' || this.loginPageIdFrom == this.cfg.startModule)
>             this.loginPageIdFrom = moduleId;
>         this.goLogIn();
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

The app goLogin example logic:

> ```
> public goLogIn(): void {
>     this.mainMenu().selectById(this.cfg.startModule);
>     this.navigateTo(this.cfg.loginPage);
> }
> ```

The app navigate example:

> ```
> public navigateTo(routeId: string): boolean {
>     var rr: string = routeId;
>     if (rr == 'home') //Handle the fact that module home is routeid as '' (as Durandal default route)
>         rr = '';
>     return m_router.navigate(rr);
> }
> ```

Where the m_router is the router module:

> import m_router = require('plugins/router');

Finally in after the login takes place in the login viewmodel you use the app.navigateTo to go back to the original route.